# Firefox extension/userscript to prevent accepted answer from sticking to top on Stack Exchange

Tags: gratis, firefox, stack-exchange

Stack Exchange often places the accepted answer on top of all other answers.

I often get tricked into implementing the first answer, only to realize that it is vastly inferior to the second answer, with has much more upvotes. ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460996))

So, I am looking for an extension that would sort answer strictly by votes.
The order would not be affected by an answer being accepted or not.

Requirements:

- Works on Firefox
- Free, ideally open source

Comment: Have you checked with [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script), Nicolas? I cannot access my home machine currently (OOO=OutOfOffice), but remember there was a quite extensive SE-specific UserScript I've installed there. Not sure whether it includes what you're after, as I rarely noticed the described problem – which might be due to the fact the script takes care of exactly that :) Maybe Shub adds it to his [SE Additional Optional Features](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/se-additional-optional-features) when asked.

Comment: @Izzy: Searching for "accepted" does not lea to any obvious result there. Nor does searching for "sort" :-/

Comment: I'm just walking all those 17 pages manually. If I find something, I'll put a note here – if not, I'll check at home in the evening. Will let you know.

Comment: Lol @Izzy why not? Not at home right now but doesn't the 'votes' sort do what you want...? I can't test it right now, so I might be wrong.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I'm not the OP – and no, the 'votes' sort cannot lookup my machine at home :) But the script I had in mind doesn't do what Nicolas is after: [SE Modifications](https://stackapps.com/q/2138/21728) does a real lot of useful things, but not that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've made a userscript to do this - it adds another sort button on the answers tab:

[image]

I've tested it on Firefox and Chrome on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/python-code-to-pick-out-all-possible-combinations-from-a-list).

It will take the votes and sort them in descending order without taking into account which is the accepted answer (which it seems the 'votes' tab does currently).

To use, install [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) (on Firefox) or [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) (on Chrome) and [install the script](https://github.com/shu8/SE-Answers_scripts/raw/master/sortStrictlyByVotes.user.js):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Sort by votes, properly...
// @namespace    http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810
// @version      1.1
// @description  Adds a new option on questions to sort answers by votes *ignoring the accepted answer* - unlike the current 'votes' tab.
// @author       ᔕᖺᘎᕊ (http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810)
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

setTimeout(function() {
    if ( $('.answer').length ) {
        $('.answer').each(function() {
            votes = $(this).find('.vote-count-post').text();
            $(this).attr('data-votes', votes); //add a 'votes' attribute to all the questions
        });

        var $wrapper = $('#answers');

        $('#answers-header').insertBefore('#answers');
        $('#tabs').append('<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="realVotesTab" title="Answers with the highest score first (ignoring accepted answers!)">real votes</a>');

        $('#realVotesTab').on('click', function() {
            $('#tabs a').removeClass('youarehere');
            $(this).addClass('youarehere');       
            //Thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14160529/3541881
            $wrapper.find('.answer').sort(function(a, b) {
                return +b.getAttribute('data-votes') - +a.getAttribute('data-votes');
            }).prependTo($wrapper);
        });    

        //Comment out the next 3 lines if you do not want the 'real votes' tab to automatically be chosen when yuo first arrive at a question (ie. prepend "//" to the next 3 lines)
        if(document.URL.indexOf('?answertab=') == -1) {
           $('#realVotesTab').trigger('click');
        }
    }
}, 100);
```

Note: This is largely based on my [previous script to sort bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252238/260841) :)

Comment: +1 Works great! Would it be possible to show the "real votes" tab by default, without having to click on it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Done; if you want to stop it from auto-choosing the real votes tab - just comment out the lines where it says (near the bottom) :)

Comment: Is this available for Stylish, by any chance?

Comment: @SarahofGaia no sorry :/...

Comment: Okay. It's okay.